# Setting background text in Scatter Plot using Highcharts API

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way we can set background text in scatter plot? we have chart.plotBackgroundImage to set the image as background. But, I want to set text as background. please help.

Comment: Could you show how this should look like? Maybe you simply want to use [`annotatons`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for something like this. https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/EpxxJr?editors=1010

Comment: So it's done :) Just a reminder, you can control zIndex: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBjMoQ?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Highchart's SVG renderer` to give a background text to your chart. You just need the `x` and `y` position for the text. This could work for any chart not only scatter plot.

```
chart.renderer.text('This text is background text', 150, 130)
    .css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '16px'
    })
    .add();
```

The `chart` is the chart object for the chart you are drawing, `150` and `130` are `x` and `y` values. Have a look at this example Codepen
https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/EpxxJr?editors=1010

Comment: Really appreciate your repsonse. This is exactly how I want to display. Will give it a try.